# How to pass the class path to ipython's notebook when called from ipzope?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, buildout

I've been using iypthon as set from ipzope (buildout) for a while and it works without problems.

Now I'm trying to use ipython's notebook and I cannot set it up properly.

When I create a new notebook it stops IPython's Kernel with an `ImportError` (see below).
I guess that the created Thread in `IPython.html.notebook.start()` opens the `webbrowser` without passing the `sys.path` from the calling process.

My workaround is to add the paths in `ipzope` to `PYTHONPATH`.

When I add all the paths then ipython's notebook works perfectly and I can debug and manipulate Plone.

If I only add `ipython`, `pyzmq`, `Jinja`, and `tornado` to `PYTHONPATH` ipython's notebook works but it has no access to the `ipzope` vars (`app`, `utils` etc.)

**Question:** Any hint how to pass the paths to ipython's notebook without using `PYTHONPATH`?

I start ipython's notebook from `ipzope` with

```
sys.argv[1:1] = "notebook --ip=192.168.45.135 --profile=zope".split()
```

The ImportError is:

```
IPython Notebook 14-03-22 14:57:17.141 [NotebookApp] Connecting to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50948
2014-03-22 14:57:17.143 [NotebookApp] Kernel started: b573fbc0-5dee-410b-91cb-01afd2e9acce
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quote `Min RK` [IPython developer](https://github.com/minrk):

> "When you start plain terminal IPython, the shell is created in the
>   same process. That means that IPython executes in the same context as
>   the changes you have made to sys.path, so the changes have the desired
>   effect. In the notebook, only the notebook server exists in that
>   context. Kernels are started as subprocesses, and thus recreate
>   sys.path at startup, following the standard procedure for a Python
>   process, and do not inherit any runtime changes to sys.path that may
>   have happened in parent processes."
>   (https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/5420)

### My Solution

Thus the only way to pass the path to notebook is via `PYTHONPATH`.

My workaround by now is to set `os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ':'.join(sys.path)` in the script. With this you don't need to mess the PYTHONPATH (if any) of your system and you make sure that all the necessary paths will be passed to the kernel.

The `os.environ` is passed as `env` argument of `Popen` to the subprocess in `launch_kernel` (`.../ipython-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/IPython/kernel/launcher.py`).

If you need to use ipython's notebook and want buildout to generate the script, add the following to your buildout (e.g. in `.../Plone-4.3.2/zeocluster/develop.cfg`)

```
parts +=
...
    ipzopenb
...
[ipzopenb]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    ipython
    pyzmq
    tornado
    Jinja2
#following for nbconvert
    Pygments
    Sphinx
    ${client2:eggs}
initialization =
    import sys, os
    os.environ["INSTANCE_HOME"] = "${client2:location}"
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ':'.join(sys.path)
    sys.argv[1:1] = "notebook --ip=192.168.45.135 --profile=zope".split()
scripts = ipython=ipzopenb
...
[versions]
Jinja2 = 2.7.2
Pygments = 1.6
Sphinx = 1.2.2
```