# Django and IPython: subdirectories

Tags: python, django, ipython, jupyter

I love using IPython (or Jupyter now) notebook for certain calculations I need for my Django project. Shell_plus does the job for me. But as the number of IPython notebooks grows it gets really messy in Django project root folder. I created subdirectory called Calculations but as expected, Django does not get loaded inside such notebooks. Is there any way to smoothly append the subdirectories paths?

Comment: How do you run your notebooks? By `manage.py shell_plus --notebook` and then opening them in a browser, right?

Comment: Alex, yes, that's how I run them.

Comment: Try seting your `PYTHONPATH` in the profile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578980/how-to-pass-the-class-path-to-ipythons-notebook-when-called-from-ipzope

Comment: BTW, **solved** [here](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/865).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in comments above, [this github issue](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/issues/865#issuecomment-273561192) has the solution. I've distilled below what I think are the minimal steps.

1. Django project layout

   ```
    /project
      /someapp
      /notebooks
        ipython_config.py
      settings.py
   ```
2. Contents of `settings.py`

   ```
    NOTEBOOK_ARGUMENTS = [
             '--notebook-dir', 'notebooks',
             ]
   ```
3. Contents of `notebooks/ipython_config.py`

   ```
   import sys
   import os

   FILE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
   PROJECT_BASE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(FILE_PATH, '..'))

   # Allows the kernel to "see" the project during initialization. This
   # FILE_PATH corresponds to Jupyter's "notebook-dir", but we want notebooks to
   # behave as though they resided in the base directory to allow for clean
   # imports.
   print("sys.path BEFORE = {}".format(sys.path))
   sys.path.insert(1, PROJECT_BASE_PATH)
   print("sys.path AFTER = {}".format(sys.path))

   # Any additional initialization logic goes here
   ```
4. Launch with shell_plus

   `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook`
5. I had to create a folder for the log files

   `mkdir -p notebooks/logs`